# Record audio in video

Tags: recording

I just recorded a video conversation using the 'screenshot' function on my mac. The idea was to record the video call, but also the audio of me and the other person talking... There was NO audio recorded!

How to record audio from the screen?!

Comment: Screenshot is just that a screen shot or a recording of the **screen.** You will likely need a 3rd party utility (SnagIt springs to mind but there are likely others) to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same problem when we went to online teaching after SARS-CoV-2 hit. I found a free workaround, but there are subscription services that work. I can't say for sure that this is the best way to do it (just best for right now?):

1. Open a web-conferencing app like Zoom, WebEx, GoToMeeting, etc., and start a meeting without others.
2. Share your screen in the meeting, focussing on the video you want to record. Make sure you select to "Share computer audio" in this step.
3. Now open your preferred screen-recorder such as Screencast-O-Matic, Canvas Studio, Echo360, etc. (I don't know if the built-in recorder works), and record the shared web-conference video.

I hope this was helpful, but I look forward to better options if anyone has any! Good luck!

Comment: This reads like an ad for a specific product, somehow. It may not be your intention though, so editing it to reduce the focus on one product might help

Comment: Not my intention; I took out the link so there are a few examples in for each product type. Does that look better?

Comment: @O'Niel, when I posted this answer I was using an extra step (i.e., step 3). If you select the option to "share computer audio" from within the web-conferencing app, you can then use that same app to record.

Comment: If the answer is missing a step, please edit the answer to include it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a option to record sound from the Build-in Microphone, as shown below.

[image]

This image was take from a  2013 iMac which has a jack for an external microphone. The sound quality is better using an external microphone. If your Mac does not have a microphone jack, then you could try using a USB microphone.

Comment: But that doesn't record the audio from the other person talking in the video.

Comment: I would assume you would get the type of microphone that would pick up the sound from your voice and the sound from the speakers. For example, this [conference room microphone](https://www.wish.com/product/5c63da16fdf00b269cbb0361?hide_login_modal=true&from_ad=goog_shopping&_display_country_code=US&_force_currency_code=USD&pid=googleadwords_int&c=%7BcampaignId%7D&ad_cid=5c63da16fdf00b269cbb0361&ad_cc=US&ad_curr=USD&ad_price=10.47&campaign_id=7203534630&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIzraa9Ij66AIVM_C1Ch3xsQ4zEAQYBCABEgKv2_D_BwE&share=web)

Comment: Or this [conference room microphone](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1509469-REG/audio_technica_consumer_atr4697_usb_omnidirectional_condenser_boundary_microphone.html/?ap=y&ap=y&smp=y&smp=y&lsft=BI%3A514&gclid=EAIaIQobChMIzraa9Ij66AIVM_C1Ch3xsQ4zEAQYAiABEgJbHPD_BwE)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to capture system audio during a screen recording if you install an audio driver extension such as [BlackHole](https://github.com/ExistentialAudio/BlackHole) or [iShowU Audio Capture](https://obsproject.com/forum/resources/os-x-capture-audio-with-ishowu-audio-capture.505/).  Both are free.  When installed they become an additional sound input which may be selected like the internal microphone.